# "<a>" tags change color when a transition occurs anywhere in the page. Is this a bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.0 beta and I created a footer with the grid system.

When a transition occurs with this specific css set up the anchor tags slightly change color and even thickness increases a bit, here the example:

With a simple transition like this for an image that has nothing to do with the links on the footer:

```
.gallery-item:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

https://codepen.io/ocanodiego/pen/KXbwRX

I tested in Chrome and Firefox and so far only happens in Chrome, if this is a but is there a workaround? Is really annoying.

I have tried so far the following:

- Removed all scripts to discard some javascript intervention
- Tried to change/increase z-index to make sure the elements are on top

When I add a bootstrap carousel everytime the carousel changes slide automatically, the links on the footer will again become blurry and change color slightly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code provided in your pen doesn't do any of your described "change" when a transition (hover on gallery item) occurs in Chrome 62. Please add the carousel to your pen that I can have a look on this problem too. Not to be rude: Maybe its an optical illusion, because the image zooms? I can't see anything.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking a look, I can confirm the pixels actually change because I'm zooming it and they do change, look at the anchor tags at the bottom of the page, and hover over an image and it should occur. Maybe has to do with my computer graphics? @Felix